# How to optimize the following code segment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code segment will redirect to the predefined page after sign in. 
Now I need to pass a parameter considering a condition which is

```
agreed_user = current_user.has_agreed_to_privacy_policy?
```

I wrote the following code. I need the best optimized code segment to this.

```
def index
 if current_user
   agreed_user = current_user.has_agreed_to_privacy_policy?
   diary_count = current_user.diaries.count
   if diary_count == 0
     redirect_to new_diary_path
   elsif diary_count == 1
     unless agreed_user
       redirect_to diary_path(current_user.diaries.first, params: {a: :b})
     else
       redirect_to current_user.diaries.first
     end
   else
     redirect_to diaries_path(params: {a: :b})
   end
 else
   unless agreed_user
     redirect_to login_path(params: {a: :b})
   else
     redirect_to login_path
   end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the logic itself, you can avoid multiple nested if/else statements by using so-called [guard clause](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/GuardClause), using `return`:

```
def index
  return redirect_to(login_path) unless current_user

  diary_count = current_user.diaries.count
  return redirect_to(new_diary_path) if diary_count.zero?
  return redirect_to(diaries_path(params: {a: :b})) if diary_count > 1

  if current_user.has_agreed_to_privacy_policy?
    redirect_to current_user.diaries.first
  else
    redirect_to diary_path(current_user.diaries.first, params: {a: :b})
  end
end
```

Comment: Might as well use a guard condition on that last `if...else`, yes?

Comment: This last condition has too long lines, it doesn't fit recommended 80 characters line lenghts... so it's either exceeds line size, or increases amount of lines by expanding guard clause to 3 lines (if ...\n return\n end)